# Python if x as y

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

I often find myself doing something stupid like

```
if some_function():
    self.value = some_function()
```

which makes the function execute twice. It will be rectified by something like

```
value = some_function():
if value:
    self.value = value
```

It would be awesome if Python allowed something like

```
if some_function() as value:
    self.value = value
```

Saves some space, and is pretty legible. I'd even say that it seems pythonic.

So, I know this is not valid syntax, but is there a similar construct, that I am unaware of? Would it be worth suggesting it to the Python Software Foundation?

Comment: What should `self.value` be otherwise? You could do e.g. `self.value = some_function() or None`.

Comment: what so you want to compare ? `values` or `values and datatype` ?

Comment: What's the use case for this? I'm curious more than anything else.

Comment: Note that the barrier for adding new syntax to Python is pretty high, and *"explicit is better than implicit"*; I doubt such a proposal would make it into the language.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: if (not value), then self.value should remain unchanged

Comment: Then folkol has solved this for you!

Comment: To your last question: (1) The PSF would be the wrong place to suggest it to; the [python-ideas](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/) mailing list would be a more suitable forum, and (2) before you make such a suggestion, it would be a good idea to look through the python-ideas archives for previous suggestions along these lines (there are quite a few).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python deliberately disallows such a construct, by forcing `if` condition to be an expression, and making assignments not an expression, under the motto "Explicit is better than implicit". You are expected to write

```
value = some_function():
if value:
    self.value = value
```

(However, it works in Ruby, C, JavaScript, Java... and any other language where assignment is an expression.)

Comment: Please explain how one would do such a thing in C.

Comment: @user3267581: Pretty much exactly as you'd expect: `if (value = some_function()) { do_stuff_with(value); }`.  Many compilers will warn about this construct, though, and ask whether you really meant to say `if (value == some_function()) {...}`.

Comment: @user3267581: Indeed; a wrinkle in C is that you have to have `value` declared beforehand. Also, I (and linter) would prefer to write `if ((value = some_function()))`, to make it explicit that an assignment is what we want and it's not a typo for `==`.

Comment: It's not what the user wants though. According to his examples, if `some_function` returns false-like, then `value` should be unchanged. It's not the case with your examples.

Comment: @user3267581: No, `self.value` should be unchanged. `value` is a temporary variable unrelated to it.

Comment: Im marking this as the answer. It seems the more educated reply.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do:

```
>>> self.value = some_function() or self.value
```

Comment: Unless `self.value` has no existing value, in which case you get an AttributeError.

Comment: Right. The body of the if-statement might be more than a single statement though, which wouldn't work for your example. But yours is probably the closest thing to what I wanted

Comment: @user2357112 if that's a possibility use `getattr(self, 'value')`

Comment: @jonrsharpe: But then `self.value` is assigned a value of `None` when it shouldn't be assigned at all.

Comment: @user2357112 and if *that's* the case, use one of the other constructs.

Answer (score 0):

```
def if_to_for(condition):
    if condition: yield condition

for value in if_to_for(some_function()):
    self.value = value
```

would work as well.

If the condition is true, the loop will execute once, if it is false, it won't execute at all.

Comment: That is pretty interesting. Although its not very intuitive to read. Great job on creativity

Comment: Or even: `for self.value in if_to_for(...): pass`.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

**theoretically**:

```
if (lambda v: globals().update({'value':v}) or v)(some_function()):
    self.value = value
```

You are faster assigning the return of the function to a variable before you do the `if`. Also readability counts.